# Draw resistor with band color code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this resistor. Everybody will ask me what have you tried? But I’m first user that I can only type and know some code in latex. If you have a good look of this resistor please kindly share it to me.
[image: here it just sample that I got from internet]

Comment: This is not a circuit al symbol, so I think that `circuitikz` is not related with it. It can de bone in TikZ though. You can read the tutorials from the TikZ manual and come back when you got stuck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% \Stripe{offset}{color} long stripe
\newcommand\Stripe[2]{\draw[fill=#2,#2] ++(#1,0) +(-0.15,-0.71) rectangle +(0.15,0.71);}
% \stripe{offset}{color} short stripe
\newcommand\stripe[2]{\draw[fill=#2,#2] ++(#1,0) +(-0.15,-0.51) rectangle +(0.15,0.51);}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % wire
  \draw[gray,fill=gray!40] (-3,-0.2) rectangle (3,0.2);
  % resistor
  \draw[rounded corners,thick,gray,fill=gray!20]
  ++(0,0.5) -- ++(1.5,0) -- ++(0.2,0.2) -- ++(0.8,0)
  .. controls +(0.2,-0.5) and +(0.2,0.5) .. ++(0,-1.4) -- ++(-0.8,0)
  -- ++(-0.2,0.2) -- ++(-3,0) -- ++(-0.2,-0.2) -- ++(-0.8,0)
  .. controls +(-0.2,0.5) and +(-0.2,-0.5) .. ++(0,1.4) -- ++(0.8,0)
  -- ++(0.2,-0.2) -- cycle;
  \Stripe{-2.1}{red!80!gray}
  \Stripe{2.1}{yellow!50!gray}
  \stripe{-1.2}{orange}
  \stripe{0.2}{black}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The yellow/gray stripe should be gold (5% tolerance).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Obviously, this *is* gold. I have calibrated the color such that it approximates gold on most screens of TeX.SX users.